# Запись в Excel файл С# WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel

Нужно реализовать метод записи в Excel файл.
Пробую:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Затем:

```
private void writingInExcMethod() {
    try {
        Excel.Application ObjExcel = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet;
        ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
        ObjWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)ObjWorkBook.Sheets[1];
        ObjWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "51";
        ObjWorkBook.SaveAs("log.xlsx", Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
        Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        /**/
        ObjExcel.Quit();
    }
    catch (Exception exc) {
        MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при составлении лога\n" + exc.Message);
    }
}
```

При указании такого пути как "log.xlsx" файл не создается в текущей директории, а где - непонятно. Почему? Если указать абсолютный путь, то все ОК.
И если файл перезаписывается (повторное вызывание метода), то выскакивает диалоговое окно, где предлагают Заменить/Не заменить существующий файл.

Как сделать так, чтоб по умолчанию было выбрано "Заменить" (перезапись) и диалогового окна не было?

Comment: _"а где - непонятно"_  -- посмотрите значение Environment.CurrentDirectory

Comment: @Stack с адресом через Environment.CurrentDirectory всё ок, но файла там нет!) Интересная штука...

Comment: _"чтоб по умолчанию было выбрано "Заменить""_ -- перед записью файла, сам удаляйте его, если он есть. примерно так `if(File.Exists(путь)) File.Delete(путь)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В конструкторе формы текущую директорию можете указать явно, например:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"c:\temp";
```

а вместо `"log.xlsx"` указать `Path.GetFullPath("log.xlsx")`

Comment: А если папка с программой переместится, адрес изменится и работать не будет! Не вариант..

Comment: значит не меняйте CurrentDirectory, но GetFullPath оставьте. в Excel будет передаваться полный путь.

Comment: Отлично! Огромное спасибо!.. теперь ещё с диалоговым окном разобраться..