# импорт HTML в Excel (Com-объект, Powershell)

Tags: html, excel, powershell

Есть HTML-таблица. Как импортировать HTML в Excel, используя COM-объект? (скрипт Powershell)

Comment: а Excel и Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel установлены?

Comment: Excel установлен. а что такое Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel и зачем?

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.* - .NET-обертки для работы с COM-объектами Excel, Word, и т.д.

Comment: PowerShell создан на основе .NET

Comment: Все установлено

Comment: надо создать Excel. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476060). у вас пример работает?

Answer (score 1):

Это возможно или через Regex (что удобнее и быстрее) или через Com объект. Через COM надо прочитать всю таблицу и каждую строку, разобрать её в массив и выгрузить в csv. 
Если ваша таблица выглядит так:

```
<H3>Заголовок</H3>
<TABLE ID="table6" BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=2>
<TR><TH><B>Condition</B></TH><TH><B>\LogicalDisk(*)\Disk Transfers/sec</B></TH><TH><B>Min</B></TH><TH><B>Avg</B></TH><TH><B>Max</B></TH><TH><B>Hourly Trend</B></TH><TH><B>Std Deviation</B></TH><TH><B>10% of Outliers Removed</B></TH><TH><B>20% of Outliers Removed</B></TH><TH><B>30% of Outliers Removed</B></TH></TR>
<TR><TD>No Thresholds</TD><TD>MACHINENAME/C:</TD><TD>1</TD><TD>7</TD><TD>310</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>11</TD><TD>5</TD><TD>5</TD><TD>5</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>No Thresholds</TD><TD>MACHINENAME/D:</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>No Thresholds</TD><TD>MACHINENAME/E:</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>24</TD><TD>164</TD><TD>-1</TD><TD>11</TD><TD>22</TD><TD>21</TD><TD>20</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>No Thresholds</TD><TD>MACHINENAME/HarddiskVolume5</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>2</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
```

То код для COM будет выгглядеть так:

```
# С помощью IE создаем HTML файл.
$oIE = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$oIE.Navigate("file.html")
$oHtmlDoc = $oIE.Document

# Читаем таблицу по её ID.
$oTable = $oHtmlDoc.getElementByID("table6")

# Выгружаем строки в массив.
$oTbody = $oTable.childNodes | Where-Object { $_.tagName -eq "tbody" }
$cTrs = $oTbody.childNodes | Where-Object { $_.tagName -eq "tr" }

# Создаем массив из заголовков таблицы
$cThs = $cTrs[0].childNodes | Where-Object { $_.tagName -eq "th" }
$cHeaders = @()
foreach ($oTh in $cThs) {
    $cHeaders += `
        ($oTh.childNodes | Where-Object { $_.tagName -eq "b" }).innerHTML
}

# Конвертим строки в массив PS объектов и экспортируем в CSV
$cCsv = @()
foreach ($oTr in $cTrs) {
    $cTds = $oTr.childNodes | Where-Object { $_.tagName -eq "td" }
    # Пропускаем первую строку (заголовки).
    if ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($cTds)) { continue }
    $oRow = New-Object PSObject
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $cHeaders.Count; $i++) {
        $oRow | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $cHeaders[$i] `
            -Value $cTds[$i].innerHTML
    }
    $cCsv += $oRow
}

# Закрываем IE
$oIE.Quit()

# Экспорт в CSV.
$cCsv | Export-Csv -Path "file.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```