# C# библиотеки для генерации Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, csv

Нужна .net библиотека для генерации Excel файлов и СSV.
Да, ответов в интернете много в частности прекрасные ответы [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp?page=1&tab=oldest#tab-top)

Но датируются они в лучшем случае 2010 годом и многое могло измениться.
Так вот, какую библиотеку посоветуете на сейчас? И подводные камни, которые у вас возникали при генерации Excel файлов.

**UPD**
Нужна бессплатная библиотека.
**UPD2** Нужна бессплатная библиотека с лицензией, совместимой с проприетарным ПО.

Comment: Почитай вот это:
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-%d0%a1sv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb Сдесь описано несколько способов взаимодействия с ексель файлами + есть пример кода на оптимальном из вариантов. (простенькая либа для работы как с 2хмерным масивом)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для работы с Excel можно использовать сборку Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll
Пример работы с Excel - [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476060)

Также для работы с файлами Excel можно использовать [Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425). Примеры можно найти на github [Office Developer](https://github.com/OfficeDev).

А csv файл - это обычный текстовый файл, который можно создать например, так:

```
File.AppendAllLines(@"c:\temp\test.csv", new[] { "1,2", "3,4" });
```

Comment: Как я понимаю, оно требует наличия офиса на ПК?

Comment: да. если его нет, то можно использовать Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office.

Answer (score 2):

[EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) - очень удобная библиотека для работы с Excel, которая основана на Open XML

Легка в освоении и спасает от использования интеропа.

Имеет так же множество примеров и хорошую документацию.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/.net/excel-component.aspx), но она платная. Наличие офиса не обязательно.